# Building client api for integration within a react project

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm wondering what is the most efficient way to build an API client, to integrate that client in my react project.

Questions are :

1 Do i need to just develop a basic client api using fetch or await/sync ?
2 Coupling with redux, using reducers, any method or best practices ?
3 Accessing env varibale for setting API_URL depending on environnement

Tools used : react-scripts for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 Do i need to just develop a basic client api using fetch or await/sync ?

Yes.  Use the http framework of your choice.  JQuery, fetch, axios, whatever.  I won't go into any more detail on this one because it's prone to opinion and won't go any constructive.

> 2 Coupling with redux, using reducers, any method or best practices ?

There are quite a few redux middlewares out there for handling API calls (or more generally async actions).  [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) is one of most widely used and easiest to understand and it can also be used to [inject your API into you action creators](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument).  [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) is another good option, but is more complicated than thunk.

> 3 Accessing env varibale for setting API_URL depending on environnement

This isn't my forte, so there will be a better way to do this, but I've used a seperate script ("configuration.js" generally) that has a templated variable which I replace with the env variable's value before startup and link to it with a `script` tag in the html.  How you deploy might make this easier or harder.  I generally deploy a docker container so running a few extra commands on startup is not difficult.

Comment: Great, would follow the advice on creating a script and feeding my template with env variables, i'm using Docker as well, so this is the best way i guess to do so. Thanx :-)